# Can't sign in admin in django admin site even though superuser does exist

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm trying to sign in in the admin website with the credentials that I created as superuser. However, I get the error "Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.". Now, I checked in the shell if the user exist and if it is a superuser and it is. Just in case, I changed its password through the shell again to no avail.
I'm not sure why it's not working since the superuser does exist.

I only have this in the admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I've read the other questions about it but none have helped since my settings already have 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' and I've checked on the shell to see that everything's in order.
So what's going on?

Comment: How did you create the user? Does the user has `is_staff` True?

Comment: @JPG Thank you, just in case I added is_staff = True on the shell and that worked.